# Issue installing xgboost on Pycharm

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, installation, xgboost

I have been attempting to install xgboost using pycharm, and on two separate machines I can't get it to install, I can't find a solution that has worked online. My error message is

```
Collecting xgboost==1.0.0
  Using cached xgboost-1.0.0.tar.gz (819 kB)

ERROR: Files/directories not found in C:\Users\benmo.DESKTOP-5T4V59G\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\xgboost\pip-egg-info
```

Any answers greatly appreciated,
cheers

Comment: what method did you try to install `xgboost`

Comment: Did you try to install the package with `pip` in the command line?